# Best way to extract substring from directory path

Tags: c#

I have below strings

```
str1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\Client\v1.2\Service\test.exe"
str1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\v1.2\Service\test.exe"
str1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\v3\Service\test.exe"
str1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Client\v3.6\Service\test.exe"
```

I need to extract string till `V1.2` or `V3` or `V3.6` like below,

```
str1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\Client\"
str1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\"
str1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\"
str1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Client\"
```

What should be the best way, regex?

Comment: Define *best* please. And note that the \ need to be escaped

Comment: split on "\\v" like:  str1.Split(new string[] { "\\v" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Comment: @apomene That's a very fragile way of doing this. What if there is more than one directory in the path that starts with `v`?

Comment: System.IO.Path methods

Comment: did you try it using RegEx?

Comment: @KieranDevlin, True, I agree, that is why it is just a comment

Comment: is the `vsomething` always present?

Comment: Yes, `vsomething` always present

Comment: `str1.Split(new string[] { "\\v" }, StringSplitOptions.None)` will fine for me. It's works

Comment: " It's works –" then try this path: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\vintage\Client\v3.6\Service\test.exe"`

Comment: Is the folder you want to "extract" always the 2nd to last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex.Split(str1, @"(?<=\\)(v|V)\d+(\.\d+)?\\")[0]
```

- `(<?=\\)` is look behind for `\`, making sure version is a directory name.
- `(v|V)` case-intensive
- `\d+` a number
- `(\.\d+)?` may not have minor version
- `\\` ending path splitor.

Comment: Take your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with manual path parsing, you can use .NET to do the heavy lifting:

```
static readonly Regex VersionRegex = new Regex(@"^v\d+(\.\d+)?$", 
                                               RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

public static string SkipToApplicationRoot(string path)
{
  var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

  while (di.Parent != null)
  {
    // If the current directory is a version string, return the path to the parent directory
    if (VersionRegex.IsMatch(di.Name)) return di.Parent.FullName;

    di = di.Parent;
  }

  // No version string in the path
  return null;
}
```

In English, take the deepest folder in the path, verify if it's in the version string format, if not, repeat with the parent folder. If it is a version string, take the full path of the parent folder. If we reach the root folder, return `null` (no version string in path).

You can tweak `VersionRegex` to accept exactly the kinds of version strings you want to consider. Of course, the whole algorithm is only as reliable as your assumption that there's only one folder that fits the version string format between the full path and the root you're trying to find.

There's probably simpler code that fits your actual requirements. For the strings you've actually posted, simply going two directories up in the structure would also suffice. But as it is often said, if you can precisely formulate your requirements, you probably also have the solution already :) Given that you've given no reasoning behind what you're trying to do, it's quite possible this is an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by '\' then use a regex to find the exact match.

Test the version regex `^v[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$` [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester).
I have assumed that your version will have upto two decimal places.

**You can try like this:**

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str1 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\Client\v1.2\Service\test.exe";
    string str2 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\v1.2\Service\test.exe";
    string str3 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\v3\Service\test.exe";
    string str4 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Client\v3.6\Service\test.exe";

    List<string> versions = FetchVersionPaths(str1, str2, str3, str4).ToList();

    versions.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}

public static IEnumerable<string> FetchVersionPaths(params string[] DirectoryPaths)
{
    foreach (string directoryPath in DirectoryPaths)
    {
        // Version regex to check upto two decimal places
        Regex versionRegex = new Regex(@"^v[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$");

        List<string> destructuredPaths = directoryPath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).ToList();

        // Find the index upto version
        int versionSplitIndex = destructuredPaths.FindIndex(versionRegex.IsMatch);

        // Now get the range of the destructured paths and join them by '\'
        yield return string.Join(new string(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 1), destructuredPaths.GetRange(0, versionSplitIndex));
    }
}
```

---

**Outputting:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\Client
C:\Program Files (x86)\Server
C:\Program Files (x86)\Server
C:\Program Files (x86)\Client
```

Comment: sorry mate but this is not what OP is looking for: "I need to extract string **till** V1.2"

Comment: @MongZhu updated the answer, my bad I interpreted the question incorrectly.